# OrientDB (using orient-jdbc driver) + Commons Configuration 2

Tags: orientdb, apache-commons

I'm using OrientDB, thought its orient-jdbc driver.

I have a table where i store the application properties, lets call it TABLE_PROPERTIES, with two fields, CONFIG_KEY and CONFIG_VALUE.

The properties stored in the database overrides the properties stored in the properties file.

To do this i'm using Commons Configuration 2.

The configuration (in Spring xml) its reasonably easy:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientDataSource" depends-on="embeddedDatabase">
    <constructor-arg name="url" value="jdbc:orient:plocal:xxx\\orientdb\\databases\\test" />    
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="xx"/>
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="xx"/>
    <constructor-arg name="info" ref="props" />     
 </bean> 

<bean id="props" class="java.util.Properties" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="db.usePool">false</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:**/*.properties" properties-ref="configurationPropertiesFactoryBean"/>

<bean id="configurationPropertiesFactoryBean" class="org.apache.commons.configuration2.spring.ConfigurationPropertiesFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="databaseConfiguration"/>
 </bean>

<bean id="databaseConfiguration" class="org.apache.commons.configuration2.DatabaseConfiguration">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="table" value="TABLE_CONFIG"/>
    <property name="keyColumn" value="CONFIG_KEY"/>
    <property name="valueColumn" value="CONFIG_VALUE"/>
    <property name="configurationName" value="testPropertiesConfiguration" />        
</bean>
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error parsing query:
SELECT DISTINCT CONFIG_KEY FROM TABLE_CONFIG WHERE 1 = 1
                     ^
Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "CONFIG_KEY "" at line 1, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
<EOF>
<LIMIT> ...
<SKIP2> ...
<OFFSET> ...
<TIMEOUT> ...
<AS> ...
<FETCHPLAN> ...
<LOCK> ...
<LET> ...
<NOCACHE> ...
<PARALLEL> ...
<UNWIND> ...
";" ...
"," ...
<AS> ...
"," ...

    DB name="test"
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.parser.OStatementCache.throwParsingException(OStatementCache.java:98)~
```

The error is also simple to explain, as its related to OrientDB SQL.

This is not valid in OrientDB SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONFIG_KEY FROM TABLE_CONFIG WHERE 1 = 1
```

This is valid:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CONFIG_KEY) FROM TABLE_CONFIG WHERE 1 = 1
```

Basically, the DISTINCT keyword needs round squares between the field.

Does anyone knows an elegant and efficient way to address this?

Comment: Hi, with an elegant way you mean a way without using brackets? If yes, I don't think there's a way

Comment: The SQL is injected by Commons Configurations, so i dont have a way to change it.  So i would like to know if is there a way to extend orientdb-jdbc driver classes, in order to perform the SQL change on the fly. I have seen something similar on the OrientDB boards, but i cannot recall exactly what it was.

Comment: Even if it is a JDBC Driver, queries must be valid for the OSQL parser. The driver doesn't parse the query, it just passes it to the database. So there's no way to rewrite the query.

Comment: Isn't there a way to extend the OSQL parser? And if not, is there any alternative to make OrientDB (using the orientdb-jdbc driver) work with Commons Configuration?

Comment: OrientDB v3.0 will support the DISTINCT not as function but as standard SQL does.